# Google cardboard unity world space UI not showing

Tags: ios, user-interface, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, google-vr

I'm having an issue with world space UI and google cardboard. The canvas is attached to the character and I can clearly see it in the camera preview and when VR mode is disabled but not when VR is enabled. I've googled around for a couple hours and messed with settings in the cardboard prefabs to no avail. I also noticed that the world space UI in the demo scene that came with cardboard also has the same problem.

[image]

Comment: Do you have two different cameras in your scene? One for normal view and one for VR view? It could be that the UI is world space related to the normal camera or the VR camera is culling UI (since it is useless in VR) and your UI despite being world is still set to UI layer.

Comment: Google VR prefabs have a main camera that you assign the event camera on the canvas to which then has a script that replicates to the left and right eye cameras. No culling is set on any of the cameras. Setting the canvas to one of the two eye cameras shows no UI either.

Answer (score 0):

Which Unity version are you using?

Have you tried setting Canvas Render Mode to **World Space** and setting up the **Event Camera** to **Main Camera**

If it is still not working for you, you might want to look into the issue that I bumped into.

[World Space Canvas UI Element Issue](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/worldspace-canvas-appears-in-editor-not-in-game.277372/)

It has been a known issue from a long time from some Unity 4.* versions that was resolved in 5.* but has not appeared again in 5.3.5 and some other versions. 
Downgrading to Unity to 5.3.4f1 helps (According to the blog above).

But if you are someone who'd rather use tweaks than downgrade, then you might want to use **Quad** in **Gameobjects** and add a child **3D Text**.
I have been doing the same for my Cardboard games.

Comment: Downgrading to 5.3.4f1 worked for me.  There where some warnings when I opened my project, as it was created in a newer version, but I have not had any issues running it.